# check whether one statement imply other on differentiable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and consider the following statements.

$1$.  $\vert f(x)-f(y) \vert \le 1, \quad$ if $\vert x-y\vert \le 1$

$2$.   $\vert f'(x)\vert \le 1, \quad \forall x$

In these two statements, will one statement imply the other? I feel $(2)$ will imply $(1)$. Since $(2)$ states slope is at most one at any point $x$, in $(1)$ the average slope will be at most one in any interval of length $2$.

Comment: You might want to take a look at $(\epsilon , \delta)$ limit formulation and note that differentiability implies continuity. That might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints:**

- Are you acquainted with the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem)?
- Let $\ f(x)=\frac{\sin 10x}{4}\ $. Does it satisfy 1.? Does it satisfy 2.?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsGqz.jpg) is a proof that (2) implies (1), based on the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem):

[*Proof* by contrapositive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_contrapositive).  We prove that if (1) is not true, then (2) cannot be true, either.

Suppose (1) is false, then it follows that $|x - y| \leqslant 1$ and $|f(x) - f(x)| > 1$.  Therefore, $\displaystyle \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|} > 1$ or $\left | \displaystyle \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \right | > 1$, (3).  Now from the mean value theorem, it follows that there exists a point $c$ in the interval $(x, y)$ such that $ \displaystyle \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} = f'(c)$ or $ \left | \displaystyle \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y} \right | = |f'(c)|$.  And from (3) it follows that $|f'(c)| > 1$ which means that (2) *cannot* be true.  This is what we needed to show.